# CancelIO last over a minute when removing the HID device

Tags: visual-c++, barcode-scanner, hid

I am working in a module for my application to be able to read from a HID barcode reader device.

It is a Windows application (tested in Windows 10) and I use Visual C++.

To read I get the devicepath and call `ReadFile` with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and then use a `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for the lecture. 
If I want to close the application or the user selects another device then I trigger a second event for cancelling and call `CancelIO`.

So far so good...everthing works fine.

Now I want to detect if the user removes the selected HID device...I register a window and catch the `DeviceChange` event. Also work fine....but when I cancel the in course reading and call `CancelIO` this function takes over a minute to return.
I tried not to call `CancelIO` in this case (device removal) and can remove the device and connect it again and it works....but when I close the application, then it takes over a minute for the thread (the thread in charge of the reading) to end. So I imagine in some way the application is trying to cancel the device reading.

So my question is....what should I do when I detect the device I'm reading from is removed???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you notice that CancelIO only cancels IO issued from the **same** thread?
2. Are you sure you're not cancelling an already completed operation?
3. Please measure what exactly takes a long time during shutdown. Probably it would be `CloseHandle`.
4. Please make a simple application that demonstrates the problem. Ideally, it would only have `main()` and have a `MessageBox()` where you need to remove device.

Comment: Hi Codeguard. Thank you for your comments...1) It is the same thread how call CancelIO. The thread is stopped waiting a reading...then when the device is desconnected the UI thread notifies this thread who triggers the cancellation event unblocking the reading thread and calling CancelIO. Maybe the CancelIO is not needed in this scenario (couldn't find any information regarding this) but then when the thread is finished (Join) it last over 1 minute. If I do call CancelIO this minute is lost in the CancelIO and not when finishing the thread.

Comment: 2) As I said, maybe no CancelIO is needed when the user remove the device. But the blocking happends then when finishing the thread. Even if I add the same device again and work with it.

Comment: 3) When shutingdown the long time is lost in the Join. Is not my code.

Comment: 4) I'll try, but is not an easy scenario. I need at least to create a thread for reading. Just with one thread I won't be able to listen for device changes and cancel the reading. Moreover the method to register a listener need and HWND so I need a kind of UI.

Comment: You don't need the listener. After the `MessageBox`, you know the user has removed the device, and you can go straight into `CancelIO`. The reading thread will be the `main()` thread.

Comment: While you're stuck on `Join`, please break into debugger and look what's happening in the thread being awaited.